# Matching module code using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have never worked with RegEx and have been trying to perform validation to ensure a module code matches the correct format. A valid module code should be in the form: **CSC8001**

My code is as follows:

```
if(moduleCode.matches("^CSC8\d{3}")){ 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

This produces an invalid escape sequence error which I have been unable to resolve.

Thanks in advance, Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use:

```
moduleCode.matches("^CSC8\\d{3}")
```

`\d` is an illegal character. To make it `\d` you must use `\\d`.

`\\` escapes to form a single back slash.

Comment: Will this correctly catch the module format? Thanks for your help